# Stacking Divs side by side in CSS

Tags: css, html

I didn't want to resort to asking here but after hours of frustration I feel I have to!

I have two (could be more) divs that I want side by side. Their parent div has a fixed width and `overflow:hidden` so we can see at most one div at a time. The problem being is that they will not stack side by side! I've tried `float:left` and `display:inline` to no avail.

there is a JSFiddle example I made [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QBhmF/)

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needed to have div

```
#tab_container{
    width:2000px;
}
```

Which then gives your floats enough space to float side by side, currently they don't have enough room and so default float behaviour forces them to the next line.

http://jsfiddle.net/QBhmF/10/

Comment: No a div will automatically fill to 100% the width of it's parent which in this case is 505px; You could just set it to something so big it will always have enough room for your divs.

Comment: That's what I've gone for, seems a bit messy to oversize the container but it's working.

Comment: It is I suppose but that's how's done, take a look at http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/ for example. You could use javascript to size the container to just enough for it's contained divs if you really wanted to.

Comment: Yeah good point, when I get round to the .js I'll most likely add that in.

Answer (score 2):

Each of them divs needs `display:inline-block` and the parent needs: `white-space:nowrap` so they stay all on one line.

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/QBhmF/15/

Comment: This is not safe cross browser.

Comment: Just for me as a learning opportunity, can you tell me in which browser this doesn't work as intended? Thank you.

Comment: Support in IE is dodgy, not supported in firefox 3.0 or lower. I'm not saying you can't use it but you need to be careful and make sure it works on all browsers you support otherwise you'll need to use floats, and make sure you don't have any users using older versions of Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Try display:inline-block

Answer (score 1):

try

position:relative
float:left

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look e.g. here:
[How to float 3 divs side by side using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156712/how-to-float-3-divs-side-by-side-using-css)

Answer (score 0):

A boilerplate solution for this Ioff the top of my head) could be as follows:

```
<div class = 'container'>

<div class = 'floater'>Some text</div>
<div class = 'floater'>Some other text</div>

<div class = 'clearout'></div>

</div>

div.container {

width: 400px;
border: 1px solid blue;

}

div.floater {

float: left; 
width: 48%;
border: 1px solid red;
margin: 2px;

}

div.clearout {

clear: both; 
height: 0px; 
visibility: hidden; 
width: 100%;

}
```

Any margins applied to floaters could mess up the layout. Floaters could also have absolute dimensions rather than percentages, if you can predict their size.

HTH,

G

Comment: Edited this to better show what I meant and also, y'know, make it work. ;-)