# CSS - Issue with inline-block and transform rotate

Tags: css, vuetify.js

I'm trying to build a menu where the link items run at a 90degress angle. You'll see what I mean when you load the codepen

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BbQEPb

The problem I'm having is; even though I set the navigation drawer to "block" and the v-list items as "inline-block", They are still side by side, not stacking at that 90 degree angle down the navigation drawer.

[image: This is what I'm trying to do]

This is the CSS I've used to try and emulate that menu, but I just can't get the stack right and my CSS skills aren't that grand yet.

```
  .v-navigation-drawer .v-list {
    transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(-100%);
    transform-origin: bottom left;
    display: block;
  }
  .v-list > div {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:  center;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

As usual, I more look for pointers in the right direction rather than completed answers, but happy with either.

Thanks in advance y'all.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the parent needed to be set with nowrap on whitespace

I was simply searching for the wrong answers.

This stackoverflow issue sorted me out [Stacking Divs side by side in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4397647/stacking-divs-side-by-side-in-css)