# CSS: Placing divs left/center/right inside header

Tags: css, html, position, css-float

I've been trying to create a site with the following structure:
[image: desired structure]

But I can't seem to get the header correct (e1 left, e2 centered, e3 right). I want the three elements e1, e2 and e3 to be left, middle and right positioned. This is what I'm trying:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header">
    <div id="header-e1">
        1
    </div>
    <div id="header-e2">
        2
    </div>
    <div id="header-e3">
        3
    </div>
</div>
<div id="nav">
    links
</div>
<div id="content">
    content
</div>
<div id="footer">
    footer
</div>
</div>
```

With this css:

```
#wrapper
{
    width: 95%;
    margin: 20px auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#header
{
    margin: 5px;
}
#header-e1
{
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#header-e2
{
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#header-e3
{

    border: 1px solid black;
}

#nav
{
    margin: 5px;
}
#content
{
    margin: 5px;
}
#footer
{
    margin: 5px;
}
```

### Can someone give me tips to what I can do? The structure is going to be used on a mobile website.

UPDATE

The code I have above gives me this: 
[image: current result]

But I want the 2 centered and the 3 on the right side. I don't want to set the width to a percent because the content in the elements may vary, meaning it may be 20/60/20 - 10/80/10 - 33/33/33 or something else.

Comment: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156712/how-to-float-3-divs-side-by-side-using-css

Comment: I would not have understood your question, but then you posted your layout in paint, and all was good. ;)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### [Utilize the Magic of Overflow: Hidden](http://web.archive.org/web/20150618153020/http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/?)

If you can swap the html position of 2 & 3 like so:

```
<div id="header-e1">
    1 is wider
</div>
<div id="header-e3">
    3 is also
</div>
<div id="header-e2">
    2 conforms
</div>
```

Then you can set this css which will cause 2 [**to "fill" the available space**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZNGsh/3/) because of the `overlow: hidden` on it. So [**if 1 & 3 expand, 2 narrows**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZNGsh/4/) (shrink window down to see what happens at really small size).

```css
#header-e1 {float: left;}
#header-e2 {overflow: hidden;}
#header-e3 {float: right;}
```

Technically, you could keep your current html order and your `float: left` on both 1 & 2 and [**make 3 the flex div**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZNGsh/6/) with `overflow: hidden`. You [**could do the same with 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZNGsh/7/) by reversing the order of the html completely and setting 2 & 3 to `float: right` with 1 having `overflow: hidden`. To me it would seem best to have the middle flex, but you know your application better than I.

Comment: This is a wonderful solution. but i have a problem. e2 stretches full and e3 is out of boundary.

Comment: @codebrain: You would need to describe your problem (or illustrate it with a fiddle), as I do not know what you mean by "e3 is out of boundary."

Comment: E1 and E2 are placed inside the container and e3 went out of container.                                                        #e1
    {
   float:left;
    }                                                           
#e2
   {
    display:inline-block;
    overflow:hidden; 
   }
#e3
{
 float:right;
}  **This fixed the issue** Anyways your solution helped a lot and i upvoted it!

Comment: you should also add .header{text-align: center;}

Answer (score 5):

If you are trying to make the site with a responsive width, you can try the following (33% is roughly one-third):

```
#header-e1 {
    float: left;
    width:33%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#header-e2 {
    float: left;
    width:33%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#header-e3 {
    float: left;
    width:33%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

You could also used fixed widths for the divs. If you want the further from each other you can play with their left/right margins etc. Hope that helps!

Here is an edit for no widths:

```
#wrapper {
    position:relative; (add to wrapper)
}

#header-e1 {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    border:1px solid black;
}

#header-e2 {
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    border:1px solid black;
}

#header-e3 {
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want to do it without setting the width of each element. Is that possible?

Comment: Hmmmm...I'm not sure how no width would work with your content, but I guess you could try absolute positioning.

Comment: I revised the answer I had above for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the divs in your header a width, and float header-e3 left.

Note: They all have the same CSS properties, so just give them the same class like .headerDivs and then you don't have repeating code

Edit: here is a working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eNDPG/

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a similar idea to what RevCocnept suggested with the `width: 33%`, except using `display: inline-block` instead of `float: left`. This is to avoid removing the `div` elements inside `#header` from the flow of the page and causing the height of `#header` to become zero.

```
#header > div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 31%;
    margin: 5px 1%;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Fxxwd/)

Comment: Thank you, but I want to do it without setting the width of each element. Is that possible?

Comment: @user1539208 off the top of my head, I don't know of an easy way to do it if you want the widths of all child `div` *as well as* the space in between to add up to the width of `#header`. It would depend on how the widths of each are changing (what causes the widths to be different) and whether `#header` or `#wrapper` have fixed widths as well. Not sure if you can do this with CSS alone. Perhaps there is a way that I just don't know about though, in which case I'd be interested in hearing about it as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <div id="left">Left</div>
    <div id="right">Right</div>
    <div id="center">Center</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#left {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#right {
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

#center {
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  text-align: center;
}
```

The centered `<div>` must come as the last one in the `HTML` code.

Here's a JS Bin to test: http://jsbin.com/evagat/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

```
                        <style type="text/css">
                        body {
                        margin:0;
                        }
                        #header {
                        width:100%;
                        **strong text**margin:auto;
                        height:10%;
                        background-color:red;
                        }
                        #left {
                        width:20%;
                        float:left;
                        #margin:auto auto auto auto;
                        height:100%;
                        background-color:blue;
                        }
                        #right {
                        float:right;
                        width:20%;
                        #margin:auto auto auto auto;
                        height:100%;
                        background-color:green;
                        }
                        #middle {
                        position:relative;
                        left:0;
                        right:0;
                        margin:auto;
                        height:80%;
                        background-color:yellow;
                        width:100%;
                        }
                        #middle1 {
                        width: 80%;
                        margin:auto;
                        height:45%;
                        background-color:black;
                        }
                        #middle2 {
                        width: 80%;
                        margin:auto;
                        height:40%;
                        background-color:brown;
                        }
                        #middle3 {
                        width: 80%;
                        margin:auto;
                        height:15%;
                        background-color:orange;
                        }
                        #midmain {
                        width: auto;
                        margin:auto;
                        height:100%;
                        background-color:white;
                        }
                        #footer {
                        width:100%;
                        margin:auto;
                        height:10%;
                        background-color:red;
                        }
                        </style>

now check comment for html design.
```

Comment: <body><div id="header"> </div>
      <div id="middle">
       <div id="left"> </div>
       <div id="right"> </div>
       <div id="midmain">
        <div id="middle1"> </div>
        <div id="middle2"> </div>
        <div id="middle3"> </div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div id="footer"> </div>
     </body>