# Left/right/center divs in footer with center in middle of *body*

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a page footer with some text on the left, on the right, and centered *on the page*. I've been following examples [such as this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570107/css-placing-divs-left-center-right-inside-header) and I'm having the same problem with all of them: The content in the center div is centered between the borders of the left and right divs, *not* centered on the body. That is, if left/right are not the same width then the center is off-center.

I can't use fixed widths because I know neither the content nor the font size. I do know the content will be just a few words each.

I can't use explicit proportional widths either for similar reasons; I don't know the proportions of the content and e.g. the center may be short with a left or right side greater than 1/3 of the page width.

I don't actually *have* to use divs, I just am because that seems to be the way this is done... but anything that will get me a left + body centered + right aligned footer-style layout will work (as long as it works on all common browsers).

I don't care what happens when contents overlap; they can either overlap, or word-wrap, or do something else ugly.

Currently the closest I've gotten is this CSS:

```
#left { float:left; }
#right { float:right; }
#center { float:none; text-align:center; }
```

And this HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">...</div>
    <div id="right">...</div>
    <div id="center">...</div>
</div>
```

But I am seeing this (an extreme example):

[image]

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HCduT/

I've tried various combinations of `float`, `display`, `overflow`, and `margin`, but I can't seem to get this right.

Edit: I've also tried http://jsfiddle.net/nshMj/, recommended by somebody elsewhere, but it's got the same issue (with the disadvantage that I don't really understand what it does).

How do I make the content in the center div aligned to the page, rather than centered between the left and right divs (which have different sizes)?

Comment: You mean something like this http://jsfiddle.net/HCduT/3/ ?

Comment: @Alek Thanks. That sort of works, but line-wraps the content of the right side if it is greater than 1/3 the page width (which it can be with short center content). When I removed the word-break from the right it went back to the original problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you're after.  Here's what I did get:

1. You want the left div on the left
2. You want the right div on the right
3. You want don't want to limit the width of those to 33%;
4. You want the center to always be dead center.
5. You don't care about overlapping content

If I got that right, then try this out:  **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/3cVUQ/)**

**CSS:(The color is just so you can distinguish the content, as it overlaps)**

```
#content {
    text-align:center;
}
#container {
    position: relative;
}
#left {
    float:left;
}
#right {
    float:right;
    color: #ccc;
}
#center {
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Wow, I apologize, I both put this project on hold for a while and didn't notice this answer until now. This is exactly what I was looking for, and makes a lot of sense. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

After some research i ended with this:

**html**

```
<body>
    <div id="content">center point V center point</div>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="left">L</div>
        <div id="center">C</div>
        <div id="right">RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR</div>       
        <br style="clear: left;" />
    </div>
</body>
```

**css**

```
#content {
    text-align:center;
}
#left {
    width:33%;
    float:left;
}
#right {
    width:33%;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden !important;
}
#center {
    float:left;
    width:33%;
    text-align:center;
}

#container{
    width:100%;
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HCduT/9/)

Comment: Thanks. This also almost works except it clips the text in the divs if it is greater than 1/3 the body width. I can set `overflow:visible` on the left and center to make those work, but it doesn't work on the right because the text remains aligned to the left edge of the right div (even if I also add `text-align:right`) and just runs off screen. What I don't understand is why the left and right affect the text position of the center even when the center div is full width (as evidenced by adding `border`); if I could stop the left / right from affecting the layout of the center that could work.

Comment: If you set `overflow: scroll;` to the `#right` element?

Comment: [Then it adds a scroll bar when the content is larger than 1/3.](http://jsfiddle.net/K4DRk/)

Comment: Still limits the right side to 1/3 of the width and clips. This is deceivingly difficult...