# How do I emulate a table with divs & css?

Tags: css, html-table

A table like this one:

```
<table>

  <tr>
   <td> ... </td>
   <td> ... </td>
   <td> ... </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td> ... </td>
   <td> ... </td>
   <td> ... </td>
  </tr>

  ...
</table>
```

How can I create one using div and css display:table rules ?

Comment: similar post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053205/how-create-table-only-using-div-tag-and-css

Comment: I don't know if my case qualifies as tabular data. It's a list with information that should be displayed as a tree (it has exapand / collapse buttons). I tried using lists (ULs and DLs), but I need 3 columns, not two, and they have to be perfectly aligned. For example if 1st column has one line, and 2nd columns has 3 lines, than the 1st column should expand its height to match the 2nd column. Tables do this automatically

Comment: @thelolcat how many columns do you think is the minimum to qualify as a table (hint: more than 1)?  If you have 3 columns and each row has an A, B, and C, then it sounds like tabular data.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try this ;)

**CSS**

```
.table {
    display: table;
    width: 500px;
}
.tr { 
    display: table-row; 
}
.td { 
    display: table-cell;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="tr">
        <div class="td">asdf</div>
        <div class="td">asdf</div>
        <div class="td">asdf</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
        <div class="td">asdf</div>
        <div class="td">asdf</div>
        <div class="td">asdf</div>
    </div>
</div>
```