# Create table out of column-first divs

Tags: html, css

I want 1a and 2a to be a row that gets taller the thinner the screen is - the content will wrap within each cell.

I want 1b and 2b to be a row that takes up the remaining space on the screen.

1a + 1b and 2a + 2b are columns.

```
<div class="tbl">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">1a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">1b</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">2a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">2b</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to do this with CSS?

I tried this but it disappears in Codepen...

```
.tbl {
  display: table;
}

.col {
  display: table-column;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZjGPme

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I emulate a table with divs & css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070787/how-do-i-emulate-a-table-with-divs-css)

Comment: But that has row first, whereas mine is column first.

Answer (score 1):

`display: table-column;` behaves like [HTML col tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_col.asp), that is why your table are not showing.

Replace your `.col` to `table-cell` and your `.cell` to `table-row`

```
.col {
  display: table-cell;
}
.cell {
  display: table-row;
}
```

See docs, [Css display class](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)

Also you can use this tool to understand how html tables are converted to CSS: https://divtable.com/converter/

```css
.tbl {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.col {
  display: table-cell;
}
.cell {
  display: table-row;
}
```

```html
<div class="tbl">
  <div class="col">
      <div class="cell">1a</div>
      <div class="cell">1b</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
      <div class="cell">2a</div>
      <div class="cell">2b</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's not what I'm after, I'm afraid. I want the position of 1b and 2a swapped.

Comment: Looks cool although if I add a <br> and some more text in a cell, the corresponding cell in the same row doesn't stretch.