# How to put multiple elements in a <li> element without screwing up the line spacing?

Tags: html, css

On the right side, (under Pastas), you can see a standard collection of `<li>`s within a `<ul>`.

```
<ul></ul>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
<ul></ul>
```

On the left side (Pizzas), I put two `<p>`s in each `<li>`, so I could get the left-float and right-float effect.

```
<ul></ul>
  <li><p>item</p><p>price</p></li>
  <li><p>item</p><p>price</p></li>
  <li><p>item</p><p>price</p></li>
<ul></ul>
```

Obviously the presence of the `<p>` tags has spaced the lines too far apart.

So what is the right way to fix this?

Do I have to make a new div column just for the prices?

Thanks

[image: here]

Comment: How are we supposed to help you without any code?  We aren't psychic.

Comment: Whatever happens, _please_ don't use Comic Sans. Ever. Anywhere.

Comment: @AlienArrays [WHY NOT COMIC SANS](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=why+not+comic+sans&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&gws_rd=cr&ei=R7_kUvX5F8OKrQeIxYHwCw)

Comment: @AlienArrays it is childish, messy, and impossible to take seriously, for starters.

Comment: Actually the font isn't even chosen yet. So it can't be comic sans. I think it's a default fallback of "cursive".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use DIV instead - or try something like this:

`<p>Classic - Pepperoni, Olives, Onions <span class="text-orientation-right-css">11.99</span></p>`

You should also have a look at [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com), [blueprint](http://www.blueprintcss.org) or [960gs](http://960.gs). Perfect frameworks for non-html/css guys :)

Comment: ah - span would solve it then? Thanks for an intelligent answer!

Comment: or as mentioned a `div` - here's a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156712/how-to-float-3-divs-side-by-side-using-css

Comment: the difference is I'm trying to cram them into an <li>, which I thought made it more complicated...

Comment: why not just `<li>Classic....<span style="text-align:right">11.99</span></li>`? does this work?

Comment: The class in the span wasn't being respected at all. When I changed everything to two divs, it worked perfectly.