# Print rows in html table with for loop

Tags: php, html

My table has rows that's looped in a non-specific length because the values in the cells may be added or removed anytime. Anyway, here's the code:

```
<?php 
    $i = 1;
    foreach($items as $item => $itemValue) { 
    if ($itemValue['item_id'] == $parentItemValue['id']) {
        if (fmod($i,7)) echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td class="inner-td"><input type="checkbox" id="itemId">'.$itemValue['item'].'</td>';
        if (!fmod($i,7)) echo '</tr>';
        $i++;
    }
?>
```

The above code displays this:
[image]

I also tried `if (!fmod($i,7)) echo '<tr>'` and `if (!fmod($i,8)) echo '</tr>'` and gives me this:
[image]

Also, `if (!fmod($i,10)) echo '<tr>'` and `if (!fmod($i,11)) echo '</tr>'` and gives me this:
[image]

I want my table to look like this:
[image]

Is there a way that the cells will fill in the entire row before making a new one?

Comment: im not clear on what you actually want it to look like

Comment: You can float a lot of divs inside a <td> that spans all the other columns.

Comment: @Dagon edited the question.

Comment: Thanks @acoder. I'm not really sure. Can you give an example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156712/how-to-float-3-divs-side-by-side-using-css

Comment: @acoder you're a lifesaver! Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, I know what I'm doing enough to be deadly.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. Just change the `$maxcol` value for how many columns you want.

```
<?php
$tmp = array('test1','test2','test3','test4');
echo '<table border="1">';
$x = 0;
$maxcol = 2; // Max column
foreach($tmp as $i=>$v)
{

    echo $x === 0 ? '<tr>' : '';
    echo '<td>'.$v.'</td>';
    echo $x === ($maxcol-1) ? '</tr>' : '';
    $x++;
    $x = $x == $maxcol ? 0 : $x;

}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Comment: Thank you. But I already got the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156712/how-to-float-3-divs-side-by-side-using-css as an example given by one of my question commenters above, @acoder

Comment: Okay. Sounds good.

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow this structure. 
Note that all fields and rows are made up by myself.

```
 <tbody>

        <?php 
        require_once ('connectionWithDB.php');
        $table = "members"; 
        $array = $admin_query->viewTableData($table);
        foreach ($array as $row){
        print_r($array); 
        ?>

        <tr>
         <td> <?php $row[member_id]  ?> </td>
         <td> <?php $row[member_password]  ?> </td>
         <td> <?php $row[member_first_name]  ?> </td>
         <td> <?php $row[member_last_name] ?> </td>
         <td> <?php $row[member_DOB]  ?> </td>
         <td> <?php $row[member_address]  ?> </td>
         <td> <?php $row[member_email]  ?> </td>
         <td> <?php $row[member_phone]  ?> </td>
         <td> <?php $row[member_gender]  ?> </td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
```

Comment: Clean up your dirty code, you should try to limit how often you open the PHP server.

Comment: Sorry, this isn't the one I'm looking for. Thanks, anyway for your effort. :)