# Three column layout not working

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am trying to make a  three column layout with right/left sidebars and main content.

I am floating the left sidebar to the left and right sidebar to the right hoping for the main content to wrap around the right sidebar as it comes after the right sidebar in the HTML. When all three elements have a width of 25% of the main `div`, then the content wraps below the left sidebar `div` and doesn't wrap around the right sidebar `div`. However, when I increase the width of `main` to something like 75%, it seems to be staying in the middle.

```css
.left-sidebar {
    background: red;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}

.right-sidebar {
    background: blue; 
    width: 25%;
    float: right;
}

.main {
    background:yellow;
    width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="left-sidebar">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </div>
    <div class="right-sidebar">Filler</div>
    <div class="main">Text</div>
</body>
```

Can someone please tell me what causes this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to float 3 divs side by side using CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156712/how-to-float-3-divs-side-by-side-using-css)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you should center `.main` class. Simply add `margin:0 auto;` to your css code

```css
.sidebar-left {float:left; width:25%; background:cyan;}
.sidebar-right {float:right; width:25%; background:lime;}
.main {width:50%; background:tomato; margin:0 auto;}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar-left">left</div>
<div class="sidebar-right">right</div>
<div class="main">main</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to float all the elements:

```
.left-sidebar, main, .right-sidebar { float: left; width: 25%;}
```

and and re-oder the html:

```
<div class="left-sidebar">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
<div class="main"></div>
<div class="right-sidebar"></div>
```

Comment: .left-sidebar,
main,
.right-sidebar {
float: left;
}
<div class = "left-sidebar">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </div>
<div class = "main"></div>
 <div class = "right-sidebar"></div>

Answer (score 0):

All elements need to be labelled with float:

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6xgmh44c/)

HTML

```
<div>
    <h2 align="center">responsive solution optional title</h2>
    <div align="center" class="float-left">utmost left column</div>
    <div align="center" class="float-left">centre column</div>
    <div align="center" class="float-left">right sidebar</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.float-left {
float:left;
width:33%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your right-sidebar and main divs also need height specified in css, or some content , to be visible or else will have 0px height.

Also .main class needs to have float:left

```
.left-sidebar {
    background: red;
    width : 25%;
    float :left;
     }
.right-sidebar {
    background: blue; 
    width : 25%;
    float: right ;
    height:10px;
    }

.main { 

    background:yellow;
    width : 25%;
    height:10px;
    float:left;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you wanna do but here is an idea.
You should first wrap everything on a div and give a specific width.
Also if you want the main in the middle change the position of your main div.
For example:

```
<div class="mainWrap">
  <div class = "left-sidebar">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </div>
  <div class = "main">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
  <div class = "right-sidebar">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
</div>
```

Then the css. If you float everything to the left, you ll have your inline 3 column layout.

```
.mainWrap {
   width:100%;
}
.left-sidebar { background: red;
  width : 33%;
float :left; }
.right-sidebar {background: blue; 
  width : 33%;
float: right ;}
.main { background:yellow;
width : 33%;}
```

Here is the example
[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3h8h4fq5/)

Hope it helped