# How to make 3 column two side by side one middle my divs takes everything to left

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make  simple css layout. I want 3 box

```
{Left}  {center}  {right}
```

So I write this code

```css
#myleft {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #CC6600;
}

#mycenter {
  width: 60%;
  background-color: #f2f4f4;
}

* html #mycenter {
  height: 1%
}

#myright {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #FF6633;
}
```

```html
<div id='left'> Left </div>
<div id='mycenter'> Center </div>
<div id='right'> right </div>
```

but instead of 
    `{left} {center}  {right}`

```
{left}
{center}
{right}
```

I don't know why but it goes like this even the float is left and right

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to align 3 divs (left/center/right) inside another div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603700/how-to-align-3-divs-left-center-right-inside-another-div)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156712/how-to-float-3-divs-side-by-side-using-css

Answer (score 1):

You didn't name your div id's correctly. they should be `myleft` and `myright`

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
}

#myleft {
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  width:20%;
  background-color:#CC6600;
}

#mycenter {
  width:60%;
  float: left;
  background-color:#f2f4f4;
}

#mycenter { 
  height:1% 
}

#myright {
  float:left;
  width:20%;
  background-color:#FF6633;
}
```

```html
<div id='myleft'> Left </div>
<div id='mycenter'> Center </div>
<div id='myright'> right </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your divs into a main div and try to use **[Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)**

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.d-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#myleft {
  position: relative;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: cyan;
}

#mycenter {
  width: 60%;
  background-color: #f2f4f4;
}

#myright {
  position: relative;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex">
  <div id='myleft'> Left </div>
  <div id='mycenter'> Center </div>
  <div id='myright'> right </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

And, of course, there is **grid**. First wrap the "gridded" elements

```
<div id='wrapper'>
  <div id='left'> Left </div>
  <div id='center'> Center </div>
  <div id='right'> right </div>
</div>

#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 6fr 2fr;
}
```

Then, optionally, if you want the content of each sub-div to be centered:

```
#left, #right, #center {
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.box1 {
  flex: 1 ;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: gray;
}

.box2 {
  flex: 2;
  text-align: center
}

.box3 {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box1">
    <p> text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box2">
    <p> text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box3">
    <p> text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```