# How to display a list and div next to each other in this footer HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do a list next to it an image that links to other sites but it displays below it and I don't know why even though. I used float right but still appears below it I strange way as it is having width or something that prevent it from display right to it, so any help. I'm new in front end world.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
}

header p {
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: black;
  font-weight: 1000;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

header nav ul {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 0;
  width: fit-content;
}

header nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  margin-top: 0%;
  padding: 0 25px 25px 0;
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

header nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

main #banner {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lavender;
  background-image: url("h.jpg");
  height: 600px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

main h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 0%;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px;
  color: blue;
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

main p {
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-style: italic;
  color: blue;
}

main #mainn {
  height: 400px;
}

main .buttons {
  background-color: grey;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 3px 0 gainsboro;
}

footer {
  width: calc(100%-80px);
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 40px 40px;
  margin-top: 20%;
}

footer ul {
  color: white;
  width: fit-content;
  list-style: none;
}

footer ul li {
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
}

footer ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: white;
}

footer #second {
  display: none;
}

footer div {
  width: 60px;
  display: block;
  padding: 2em;
  margin-left: 20%;
  float: right;
}

footer div img {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}


/**Desktop**/

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-lg-1 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-lg-1 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
}


/**Taplets**/

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .col-md-1 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-md-1 {
    width: 50%;
  }
}


/**Mobile**/

@media (max-width: 767) {
  .col-sm-1 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-sm-1 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="row">
  <p>FirstProject</p>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="ass.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="seccond.html">Contact us</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="first.html">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<main>

  <section id="banner">
    <h2>
      IAM A STRONG WEB DEVELOPER <br>WITH ALOT OF SKILLS
    </h2>
    <p>
      jasdslfsdjnksknglkgrlerkgne<br>kgnekgneklgnlkgnelkgneklgnkgsfmf<br>slfmsfgfgrgsrtytyyuoukjfbd
    </p>
  </section>

  <section id="mainn">
    <p class="buttons"> Cases </p>
    <p class="buttons"> Portfolio </p>
    <p class="buttons"> youtube </p>
    <p class="buttons"> behance </p>

  </section>
</main>

<footer>
  <ul id="first">
    <li>
      <a href="ass.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="seccond.html">Contact us</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="first.html">About</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul id="second">
    <li>
      <a href="ass.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="seccond.html">Contact us</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="first.html">About</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/">
      <img src="ab.png">
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/">
      <img src="bc.png">
    </a>
    <a href="https://translate.google.com/?">
      <img src="cd.png">
    </a>
  </div>

</footer>
```

**Reference Image**
[image: Problem]

Answer (score 1):

Try the display: flex; and margin: auto; command

Answer (score 0):

I think your css is really complicated, i suggest you make it simple, modding your footer adding some divs for segmentation, and using some sugestions from this answer: [side by side 3 divs question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156712/how-to-float-3-divs-side-by-side-using-css/35676852)

i test the most simple answer in this snippet:

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row{
    width: 100%;
}
header{
width: 100%;
height: 80px;
}
header p{
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: black ;
    font-weight: 1000;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    font-family:'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
   }
   
header nav  ul{
display: block;
margin: 0 auto 0;
width: fit-content;
   }

header nav  ul li a{
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
margin-top: 0%;   
padding:0 25px 25px 0;
font-family:'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
header nav ul li{
   list-style:none;
  display:inline-block;
  float:left; 
  }
main #banner{
  width: 100%;
  background-color:lavender ;
  background-image: url("h.jpg");
  height:600px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
 }
 main h2{
text-align: center;
font-weight: 600;
margin: 0%;
text-shadow:2px 2px 5px ;
color: blue;
padding-top:10px ;
font-size: 50px;
font-weight: bold;
 }
 main p{
   text-align: center;
   overflow: hidden;
   font-size: 30px;
   font-style: italic;
   color: blue;

 }



main #mainn{
height: 400px;
  }
main .buttons{
  background-color: grey;
  text-align: center;
  line-height:100px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-shadow:0 3px 3px 0 gainsboro;
}
footer{
  width: calc(100%-80px);
overflow: hidden;
background-color: grey;
padding: 40px 40px;
margin-top: 20%;
  
 }
/*footer ul { 
 color: white;
 width: fit-content;
  list-style:none;
}
footer ul li{
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
}
footer ul li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height:50px;
  color: white;
  }

footer #second{
  display: none;  
 }

 footer div  {
  width: 60px;
   display: block;
   padding: 2em;
   margin-left: 20%;
float: right;
  }

footer div img{
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}*/



.container {
  display: flex;
}
.container > div {
  flex: 1; /*grow*/
}







/**Desktop**/
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .col-lg-1{
      float: left;
    }
    .col-lg-1 {
      width: 33.33%;
    }
}   
/**Taplets**/
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px)  {
    .col-md-1{
      float: left;
    }
    .col-md-1 {
      width: 50%;
    }
}  
/**Mobile**/
@media (max-width: 767) {
    .col-sm-1{
      float: left;
    }
    .col-sm-1 {
      width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>FirstProject</title>
</head>
 <body>
<header class="row" >
 <p>FirstProject</p>
 <nav>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="ass.html">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="seccond.html">Contact us</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="first.html">About</a>
  </li>
</ul> 
</nav>
</header>
<main>
  
<section id="banner">
<h2>
  IAM A STRONG WEB DEVELOPER <br>WITH ALOT OF SKILLS
</h2>
<p>
  jasdslfsdjnksknglkgrlerkgne<br>kgnekgneklgnlkgnelkgneklgnkgsfmf<br>slfmsfgfgrgsrtytyyuoukjfbd
</p>
</section>

<section id="mainn">
  <p class="buttons">  Cases  </p>
  <p class="buttons">  Portfolio  </p>
  <p class="buttons">  youtube  </p>
  <p class="buttons">  behance  </p>

  </section>
</main>

<footer>
  <div class="container">
      <div>
        <ul  id="first">
          <li>
            <a href="ass.html">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li  >
            <a href="seccond.html">Contact us</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="first.html">About</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
        <ul id="second">
          <li>
            <a href="ass.html">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="seccond.html">Contact us</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="first.html">About</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/">
          <img src="ab.png"> 
        </a>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/">
          <img src="bc.png"> 
        </a>
        <a href="https://translate.google.com/?">
          <img src="cd.png"> 
        </a>
      </div>
  </div>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thankyou, excuse me for complexity I am just a beginner :D

Comment: but why did you commented some of the CSS code, it was for handling the spaces and some things like that, does it have something wrong?

Comment: in my opinion, is easy only use the flex container and the result is almost the same with less complexity, but is notting wrong with your styles if you need it.